# __try/_except does not catch "int 3" debug trap on x64

Tags: c++, visual-c++, try-except

I had some code working well on x86 :

```
 __try
{
    func();
}
__except (handler(GetExceptionInformation(), GetExceptionCode()))
{
}
```

catching the "int 3" instructions which were inserted Just-in-time inside the calls beyond `func()` so that I can debug my application in the same process. 
Porting this on x64, the handler is not called anymore and I don't really understand why...

Is anyone out there with an idea ?

Comment: It is a microsoft extension yes, this is why I precised visual C++ in the tags

Comment: Sorry didn't see that, only looked at the C++ tag.

Comment: FYI I managed to get my code work again with `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` but I still don't understand why __try/__except does not get the job done anymore